# how to print uiview in label (swift3)

Tags: ios, uiview, view, label, uiaccessibility

I am trying to print a uiview in a label. I don't know if I should put accessibilityIdentifier or not. When I did put accessiblitiyIdentifier in my whole app loaded but was all black.

```
@IBOutlet var pink: UIView!
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.text = pink
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AccessibilityIdentifier can use for UI Automation scripts, 
label.text = pink wont be compile
you can use   label.addSubview(pink)

Answer (score 0):

`label.text` is of type `String` and `pink` is of type `UIView!`, that shouldn't even compile?

Comment: So its not possible to print a uiview in a label?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.. I guess you can add a subview to your label `label.addSubview(pink),` but even storyboard doesn't allow you to add a `UIView` inside a `UILabel`